# Pass a list of variable names to a function using {{foo}}

Tags: r, purrr

#### Problem

I would like to know how to pass a list of variable names to a `purrr::map2` function for the purpose of iterating over a separate data frame.

The `input_table$key` variable below contains `mpg` and `disp` from the `mtcars` dataset. I think the names of the variables are being passed as character strings rather than variable names. The question is how I can change that so that my function recognises that they are variable names(?).

In this example I am trying to sum all of the values in the `mtcars` variables `mpg` and `disp` that fall below a set of numeric thresholds. Those variables from `mtcars` and the relevant thresholds are contained in `input_table` (below).

#### Ideal result

```
percentile   key    value  sum_y
  <fct>     <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 0.5        mpg    19.2   266.5
2 0.9        mpg    30.1   515.8
3 0.99       mpg    33.4   609.0
4 1          mpg    33.9   642.9
5 ...        ...    ...    ...
```

#### Attempt

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
# Arrange a generic example
# Replicating my data structure
input_table <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(mpg, disp) %>% 
  map_df(quantile, probs = c(0.5, 0.90, 0.99, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(
    percentile = factor(c(0.5, 0.90, 0.99, 1))
  ) %>% 
  select(
    percentile, mpg, disp
  ) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -percentile)

# Defining the function
test_func <- function(label_desc, threshold) {
  mtcars %>% 
    select({{label_desc}}) %>% 
    filter({{label_desc}} <= {{threshold}}) %>% 
    summarise(
      sum_y = sum(as.numeric({{label_desc}}), na.rm = T)
    )
}

# Demo'ing that it works for a single variable and threshold value
test_func(label_desc = mpg, threshold = 19.2)

# This is where I am having trouble
# Trying to iterate over multiple (mpg, disp) variables
map2(input_table$key, input_table$value, ~test_func(label_desc = .x, threshold = .y))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is curly-curly (`{{}}`) is used for unquoted variables as you are using in your first attempt. In your second attempt you are passing quoted variables to which the curly-curly operator does not work. A simple fix would be to use `_at` variants of `dplyr` which accepts quoted arguments.

```
test_func <- function(label_desc, threshold) {
  mtcars %>% 
    filter_at(label_desc, any_vars(. <= threshold)) %>% 
    summarise_at(label_desc, sum)
}

purrr::map2(input_table$key, input_table$value, test_func)

#[[1]]
#    mpg
#1 266.5

#[[2]]
#    mpg
#1 515.8

#[[3]]
#  mpg
#1 609

#[[4]]
#    mpg
#1 642.9

#[[5]]
#    disp
#1 1956.7
#.....
```